# Sending parameters via url during reload

Tags: javascript, html, url, window.location

I am doing an ajax request and in the success callback I want to refresh the page to reflect the changes. I am trying to pass parameters to the same page as I refresh that page.

The url is something like:

`http://localhost:8080/details#component/12` to which I am appending the parameter as said below.

```
window.location.href += "?code=approved";
window.location.reload();
```

The above works in Firefox but not in IE, can you please help here?

Chris.

Comment: Smith, I forgot to say that the url has a hash, I have updated the question. I don't completely get what you are trying to say, I have IE9 and the dev tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these for IE:

```
window.location.reload(false); // To get page from cache
window.location.reload(true); // To get page from server
```

Answer (score 1):

The hash is the problem; you append your data to the URL fragment (part after the #) The fragment isn't send to the server, ie the url doesn't change so no need to request the page again. Try manually adding '#some_text' to the url in your browser and see what happens ;)

Try something like this:

```
var newloc = document.location.href;
if(document.location.hash){
    // remove fragment
    newloc = newloc.substr(0, newloc.indexOf(document.location.hash));
}
newloc += document.location.search ? ";" : "?"; // prevent double question mark
newloc += 'code=approved';
// append fragment back to url
```

Answer (score 1):

if `window.location.hash` is empty, you cant assign to location.href a new value without using a correct function (at least tested in chrome).

try the `window.location.replace`:

```
if (!window.location.hash) 
    {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href + "?code=approved")
    }
```